# Template not loading in angular 1.5 directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I've seem many questions like this in the site, but not of them worked for me.

I have this in app.js

```
   (function(){
           var app = angular.module("freelingApp", ["ngRoute"]);
           app.controller("MainController",
                   ["$http", "$scope",
                   function($http, $scope){
                          ...some code here...
                  }]);
          app.directive("dataTable", function(){
                                     return{
                                             transclude:true,
                                             replace:true,
                                             restrict: 'E',
                                             templateUrl:'data-table.html'
                                     };
                                   });

})();
```

Both app.js and data-table.html are at the same level in the directory

My index.html is like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
   ... some code here ...
  </head>

   <body ng-app="freelingApp" ng-controller="MainController">
       ... some code here...
       <div>
          <data-table></data-table>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the contents of my data-table.html (for the time being because I'm testing) are:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: Can you provide the proper location of your `data-table.html` relative to your `index.html` and the full URL you are using locally in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with the the other framework I was using, Django, so changing the templates relative URL to an absolute URL fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you use templateUrl, it should be relative to the web root url;
Please refer this: [Angular directive templateUrl relative to .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103724/angular-directive-templateurl-relative-to-js-file)