# Angular JS directive - location of CSS file relative to HTML

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My directive uses an HTML file. The HTML file uses a CSS stylesheet. I need to distribute the directive js, HTML and CSS files, so the CSS location definition needs to be relative to the HTML.

Note: [This is how I solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103724/angular-directive-templateurl-relative-to-js-file) the location of the HTML, I have pending to solve the location of the CSS file.

I put the CSS file in the same folder as the HTML file, and then defined in the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='somefile.css'>
```

however this points to the domain root, not to the HTML file location.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using gulp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two ways to fix your issue as you don't know where the directives are located:

**Solution 1 - Ancient HTML Way**

If the length of the CSS is small, you can directly include it in your template HTML itself, through the style tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
    Add style rules here
</style>
```

**Solution 2 - The Angular Way(most recommended)**

Use **ngHref** directive.

In your directive.js code, you can just put the path of the directive.html to a scope/rootScope variable and then you can access it from the directive.html

**In directive.js**

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
     scope.htmlPath = <path of templateURL>;
 }
```

**In directive.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{ htmlPath }}/filename.css">
```

***Note:***

I hope you are not using Gulp to build the angular JS code. But, If your are using gulp, you can add a gulp task and pipe all the CSS to a single CSS and can inject to your index.

Comment: Using hRef didn't work for me, the CSS file and the HTML file (the template) are in the same folder. Therefore, I tried to use `<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="filename.css">` in the directive but it looks for the CSSfile in the domain root.

Comment: @ps0604 The path is dynamic right. Although it is in same folder, you need to get the path of the template HTML and put it in a scope variable as you don't know where your HTML resides. And then pass the scope variable to ng-href like as mentioned in the above example.

Comment: please edit the description and post your directive.js and directive.html..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make separate directories for css and html(template files)
and use full path from root to the css folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/angualr/css/style.css'>
```

Comment: that's not what I'm trying to achieve, as I don't know where the directive files will be located.

Comment: Still if you use the stylesheet in any html, if it is loaded it will append the url and then your file name.

eg: if you are on page `abc.com/abc`
then your stylesheet will load from `abc.com/angualr/css/style.css` if you use `/angualr/css/style.css` with backslash

if you are on page `abc.com/abc`
then your stylesheet will load from `abc.com/abc/angualr/css/style.css` if you use `angualr/css/style.css` without backslash

I hope you understand what I mean.